# Overloading class generics in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, inheritance, overloading

I am running against the following problem that I cannot seem to solve (I simplified the classes for this post). I eventually want to specify a variety of requests. These have a certain hierarchy which I plan to model using inheritance. As a starting point, I created an abstract base class:

```
export abstract class RequestBase<TResult> {
    public async execute(): Promise<TResult> {
        const response = await this.transmit();
        return this.getResult(response);
    }

    private async transmit(): Promise<any> {
        // Code that transmits the requests, and yields a response, typed "any".
    }

    protected abstract getResult(response: any): TResult;
}
```

`getResult` will be transforming the response object to a type defined by the deriving class. I plan to have more abstract classes on top of this, e.g:

```
export abstract class RequestDerived<TResult> extends RequestBase<TResult> {
    constructor() {
        super(); // some parameterization suited for this request type.
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into, is that I am not always interested in the result of requests. This would mean that `TResult` is `void`. Ideally I would be able to write down something like this:

```
// A request that will convert the response to a number.
export class FirstRequest extends RequestDerived<number> {}

// A request for which we do not care about the result.
export class SecondRequest extends RequestDerived {}
```

This notation is possible when I specify the generic constaint on `RequestDerived` as `<TResult = void>`, but this would still force me to implement `getResult` in `SecondRequest` which would just be a dummy function.

What conceptually want to achieve, is to have a `getResult` implementation for `TResult = void`, and have the derived classes specificy it when `TResult != void`. Something like:

```
export abstract class RequestDerived<TResult> extends 
    RequestBase<TResult> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// Note: No longer abstract - we know the implementation for TResult = void.
// Not allowed: [ts] Duplicate identifier 'RequestDerived'. [2300]
export class RequestDerived extends RequestDerived<void> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    protected getResult(response: any): void {
        return; // We don't care about the result!
    }
}
```

Is there some way to achieve this without having to define two differently names classes? The reason why I want to try to avoid this, because this carries over to the derived classes (all classes down the hierarchy would have two version too).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly. It seems like you're looking for a conditional abstract method. I.e. you're looking for an abstract method that certain sub-types do not need to implement. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. In this example, I want to enforce that all derived classes of `RequestDerived<T>` implement `getResult` while classes that derive `RequestDerived` or `RequestDerived<void>` need not to.

Comment: Maybe a more clear way to convey my intention: I want to extend from `RequestDerived` if I do not care about the response (without being forced to implement anything), and I want to derive from `RequestDerived<T>` if I do care about the response. In this case I would also have to define a function (and should be forced to do so) to obtain my T from the response.